# How to use macports modules with the default version of Python preinstalled with Mac OSX?

Tags: python, macports

I have a trouble with the install of the source distribution of potrace called potrace-1.10.tar.gz (http://potrace.sourceforge.net/#downloading) on Mac OSX Leopard 10.5.8.

So, I decided to install potrace with macports ("port install potrace") and I would like to use it with the preinstalled version of Python, the version 2.5.
I don't want to work with macports because I use MAMP. All the other libraries I use are installed without macports.

Is it possible to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: With regard to potrace, I don't see where you would need to use anything python related at all. MacPorts installs a binaries and man pages with the potrace port only. If you just want to execute this potrace binary from a Python script you could do that with any version. What kind of restrictions do you see there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, MacPorts maintains its own versions of libraries and does not use libraries provided by Mac OS X. Reason for this is that MacPorts targets multiple releases of Mac OS X, where each release ships different libraries. Additionally, Apple is known to be slow at fixing security bugs in libraries provided by Mac OS X and might change them on minor software upgrades without notice.

See also these two questions and answers in the MacPorts FAQ:

- http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#syslibs
- http://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#ownlibs

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Raim.
I will continue my work using subprocess.